# How to configure Webpack 5 bundle to use global jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have a web page I'm loading jQuery on, with a script tag that points to a CDN. I'm loading jQuery into the global scope, and have small bits of JS throughout the site which use it - this is all working fine, and I'd like to continue loading jQuery this way.

Separate from that, I'm using using Webpack 5 to bundle several script files together. These scripts also use jQuery in them.

I'm just now learning that Webpack scopes its scripts. How do I get the Webpack-bundled scripts to be able to see and use my global jQuery?

Apologies if this is a dumb/old question, but I've been struggling to find an answer. Thnx!

Comment: Can you share what results you're seeing currently? Is Webpack bundling jQuery in itself?

Comment: Webpack is not bundling jQuery, instead jQuery is loaded first with a normal script tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding the following to your config:

```js
externals: ['jquery']
```

See here about the [webpack externals option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

Comment: Thank u, cant believe i missed this!

Comment: Happy to help! Webpack is sprawling, it's so easy to miss something.