# Webpack and Jquery - $ is not defined

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack

Working first time on using Webpack in a ASP.Net Core project and running in to an issue bundling jQuery

```
$ is not defined
```

webpack.config.json

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const bundleFileName = 'bundle';
const dirName = 'wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        mode: argv.mode === "production" ? "production" : "development",
        entry: ['./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js', './wwwroot/js/site.js', './wwwroot/scss/site.scss'],
        output: {
            filename: bundleFileName + '.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName)
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.s[c|a]ss$/,
                    use:
                        [
                            'style-loader',
                            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            'css-loader',
                            'postcss-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery"
            }),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: bundleFileName + '.css'
            })
        ]
    };
};
```

I have tried and exhausted all possible variations I could find on the internet without any luck.

Using `npm run build` during the .Net build process to create the bundles

Comment: That's your webpack config, but are you running webpack anywhere? How are you referencing the libraries after? Without a [mre], it's very hard to say what you're doing wrong

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  Added an update, not sure if it answers your question. Pretty new to webpack

Comment: Please, take the time to read the [mre] page. You cannot tell us what you're doing, you need to show us, by adding the relevant code

Comment: Depending on how you're loading `jQuery`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315650) may help.

Comment: Can you share your scripts?

Answer (score -1):

"`$` is not defined" means that at the time when your library tried to do something with jQuery, jQuery itself either wasn't loaded or loaded incorrectly. Make sure that jQuery loads correctly first, and only then can the rest of the code use this library. Usually it is enough to put a jQuery call before all other calls.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have verified that the bundle is loaded first before I try and access jQuery