# using jquery CDN with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, cdn

I'm trying to compile project using webpack.
I'd like to use jquery by pointing to CDN

Following [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals) this is done by adding `externals` property to `webpack.config.js`

So here's what I have:

**index.html** (within the `<head>` element)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>web site title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- main body -->
    <div id="main_b">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <!-- site page container -->
        <div id="pageCont">

        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>

<script src="../js/index.js"></script>
<script src="../js/header.js"></script>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
externals: {
    // do not bundle jquery - use external at run time
    jquery: 'jQuery',
  },
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315120/how-to-configure-webpack-5-bundle-to-use-global-jquery), I also tried

```
externals: ['jquery']
```

but both ways are not working.
Compilation succeeds, but in runtime jquery is not recognized

when using

1. `externals: {jquery: 'jQuery',}` exception

   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
2. `externals: ['jquery']` exception

   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

### UPDATE - some more info:

1. As I do not 100% understand how everything works here so not sure if it is important - but jquery is not installed locally.
2. At first I had only the `index.html` pointing to the CDN, and without any additional code (not in `webpack.config.js` (that is, externals) nor in `index.js` (import), runtime exception is `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I can see indeed the resulting html does not contain this jquery CDN script tag but only to `index.js` and `header.js`

**3. the full webapp.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  
  entry: {
    index: './src/client/js/index.js',
    header: './src/client/js/header.js'
  },
  
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    //clean dist before new build
    clean: true
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management',
    }),
  
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "*", context: "./src/client/html/static/"},
      ],
    })
  ],
  
  module: {
    rules: [
  
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
  
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  
  externals: {
    // do not undle jquery - use external at run time
    jquery: 'jQuery',
  },
  // externals: ['jquery']
};
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there a specific reason for this? Do you want to use a cached version of jQuery to save space? Are you trying to just use a CDN with easier DX?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Opsss...probably my luck of experience. I do not exactly know how to answer...what I simply want is use `jQuery` in the script. my understanding is the pointing to the CDN means - using global `jQuery` without the need to bundle the jQuery library.  And that this is good for space, traffic and performance.  Isn't it? Isn't it the better way? Any thoughts about the problem I am having?

Comment: Do you want to bundle your app efficiently, or do you want to conveniently use jQuery without a build tool? Those two options don't necessarily work well together.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy please elaborate a bit, I want to _conveniently use jQuery_. What does **efficient** exactly mean and what is it in the build process that prevents that? Truly, my current understanding is limited, so I do not fully understand your remarks. Maybe If you write your preferred way to do it - I will understand better.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why you're using jQuery with webpack and without a package manager. You don't need webpack if you just use jQuery from the CDN. webpack is useful if you need more complex bundling behavior or want to install dependencies from npm, without using a CDN.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy **1.** I am not using `webpack` **for** `jQuery`. I'm just building a site that currently use only `jQuery`, and maybe (**probably**) will use some npm packages in the future. **2.** It might be that you are right and that I do not really need `webpack` at all. This is part of what I trying to understand. **3.** Having said that, I guess there is still a way of working with jquery CDN in a project that is compiled with webpack - even if  it is not needed. isn't it? The question you raised is important but a little less relevant with the actual issue. I think.

Comment: If your goal is to learn webpack, then I'd recommend using npm and bundling jQuery normally. If you're not ready to do all that, it's fine to just use CDNs with static HTML files for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246413/discussion-between-ojnsim-and-nick-mccurdy).